# XML Feed invalid in drupal 7

Tags: views, feeds

Am trying to create xml feed through views feed generation to get the node content values. I have mapped the fields and i am getting the feed also, but a single space while generating feed in front of the xml feed. i.e before tag `"<?xml"` I am getting one single space. So that my feed page it's showing white space in Firefox and I can find the space in chrome browser. Is there config issue will be there or any thing else? Can anyone give me solution for this?

Comment: Could it be a space in a views related template, or a ?> in a custom module of yours?

Comment: Or a space at the beginning of the settings.php

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a detailed description about this problem and a possible debugging solution here: https://drupal.org/node/1275042#comment-7814971

In my case, [Views Slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) was problematic, I just created a tiny patch for that:
https://drupal.org/node/2078689#comment-7815015

---

For convenience, I'm copying my post linked above:

> As **merlinofchaos** said, this really has nothing to do with Views. The
>   "fix" in #6 is NOT actually a fix...
>
> In my case, I had two whitespaces in front of the `<?xml` tag, so the
>   RSS feed started like this: "  `<?xml`". I never thought I will find the
>   source of the problem with such an ugly solution, but this is quick
>   and works - it's really dirty, so use it only on a local development
>   copy, do NOT test it on a production site:
>   https://drupal.org/node/175137#comment-1526410
>   in `includes/module.inc` file, in the `module_load_all()` function, after the
>   `drupal_load('module', $module);`, **soyarma** suggests you to put in the
>   following line temporarily: `print $module.'|';` This way you'll get a
>   list of your modules in the beginning of the output separated by the
>   pipe (`|`) character. When there are unnecessary whitespaces before the
>   module's name and the pipe character, then you just found the buggy
>   module.
>
> For example, in my case, **[Views Slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) was the source of the problem**:
>   `views_bulk_operations|views_content|  views_slideshow|views_slideshow_cycle` (this is just the end of the huge list)
>
> As you can see, there are two spaces before `views_slideshow`. This is
>   where I should start searching for the source of the problem. I found
>   it in `views_slideshow/theme/views_slideshow.theme.inc`: the code starts
>   with two whitespaces, and the PHP block is just after that: "  `<?php`"
>   You can also see it here:
>   [http://drupalcode.org/project/views_slideshow.git/blob/d9fd60c20add43a7b...](http://drupalcode.org/project/views_slideshow.git/blob/d9fd60c20add43a7b4c133522cbb686dc98d7b7f:/theme/views_slideshow.theme.inc)
>
> And YESSS, after deleting the two spaces, http://validator.w3.org/
>   congratulated me that my RSS feed is valid. Thank you, **soyarma**!
>
> Don't forget to revert the changes in `module.inc` (**don't ever hurt the
>   core's code! :)** ), and delete the `print $module.'|';` line.
>
> I'll report an issue to the Views Slideshow's queue, and I hope that
>   this helped someone.
>
> ====
>   EDIT:
>   I reported the bug to the issue queue, and also created a patch, see [#2078689: Unnecessary two whitespaces before the PHP code
>   block in views_slideshow.theme.inc, which can cause RSS feeds to get
>   invalid](https://drupal.org/node/2078689).